# C#: cannot retrieve attribute value from XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

there is my XML document which I would like to update, but in order to do so, first, I need to get id of one of the nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <backupatmail>
    (... backups with id 0 & 1)
    <backup id="2">
      <foldername>Dwa</foldername>
      <backupdate>16/10/2015</backupdate>
      <comment>comment will be set on UI</comment>
      <numberofparts>1</numberofparts>
      <lastsucceed></lastsucceed>
    </backup>
    (... backups with id 3 & 4)
  </backupatmail>
```

I wrote this:

```
public static int GetSpecificBackupID(XDocument xdoc, string folderName)
    {
        int lastId = (int)xdoc.Descendants("backup").Where(e => e.Attribute("foldername").Value.Equals(folderName)).Single().Attribute("id");
        return lastId;
    }
```

But I constantly get **An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred**.

Can you please point me that obvious issue? ;-)

Another thing is (let's call it bonus problem):

How to add another "where" condition to method above? I need to be pretty sure about that id, so I thought about checking foldername attribute too.

Answer (score 4):

`foldername` is not an attribute - its an element. That's why you get NullReferenceException here `e.Attribute("foldername").Value`. Correct query is

```
int lastId = (int)xdoc.Descendants("backup")
    .Where(b => (string)b.Element("foldername") == folderName)
    .Single().Attribute("id");
```

---

BTW You can use overloaded `Single` operator and remove `Where`:

```
int id = (int)xdoc.Descendants("backup")
        .Single(b => (string)b.Element("foldername") == foldername)
        .Attribute("id");
```

Comment: Thanks! Works as charm! So I think, I need this straighten up: backupatmail - root; backup - node; id (of backup) - attribute; foldername - element. Do I get this right?

Comment: everything which is in angle brackets `<foo ... >` - that is an element. Everything which is `blahblahblah="..."` - is an attribute.

Comment: simplier than I thought! Thanks again m8, great support!